# Why postfix `if` in Ruby work so strange

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I have a follows strange behaviour in Ruby:

```
var1.zero? if var1 = 1
```

> `NameError`: undefined local variable or method `var1` for main:Object

From the other side, if I do same thing in a standard `if`, all works as expected:

```
if var1 = 1
  var1.zero?
end
# => false
```

Anyone can describe how work postfix `if` in Ruby?

Comment: Do you mean `var1 == 1`?

Comment: `if var1 = 1; .. ; end` is the same as `if true; ... ; end`.

Comment: No, I mean exactly `var1 = 1`, not `var1 == 1`.

Comment: `if var1 = 1` is not exactly same as `if true` because you initialize variable `var1` and can use it inside condition. Case with `var1 = 1` I use for simplicity. In common case, this condition looks like `if var1 = function_returning_nil_or_object_instance(args)`.

Answer (score 7):

Because if I ask you

> *Isn't my daughter cute...*

you will interrupt me with

> *You have a daughter?*

before I could finish my initial sentence which was

> *Isn't my daughter cute, this is her [showing picture]*?

---

But if I ask you

> *[showing picture] This is my daughter, isn't she cute*?

you can easily respond

> *No*

Comment: That's an abstract general argument. But unfortunately ruby doesn't follow that universally. For example, the following returns `false` without any errors: `class A; def a; @a.zero? if @a = 1; end; end; A.new.a`. For some reason local variables are treated differently than instance variables (and others) as explained by @ilya-vorontsov's answer below and the linked issue.

Comment: @onlynone instance variables are always defined (`@foo # => nil` vs `foo # !> NameError`). But it's true that it's inconsistent that the value is assigned before the body of the conditional is executed.

Comment: Beautifully stated, except for one glaring error: if this question is ever put to you, the only correct answer is "Yes, your daughter is adorable".

Answer (score 4):

This is because local variables are available after assignment (and it's done in the lexical order, not in execution order).

So condition clause of postfix-if doesn't change a list of available local variables available in its body. But actually it does an assignment. You can inspect it by ignoring an exception and checking `var1` value:

```rb
var1.zero? rescue nil if var1 = 1
puts(var1)
```

Also you can notice that instance variables work in a different way: they doesn't raise an error about undefined variable.

For additional info please take a look at an [issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16631#note-2) in ruby bug-tracker.

Answer (score 1):

It will go left to right, first it will read `var1.zero?` and then `if var1 = 1`

```
var1.zero? if var1 = 1
```

that's why it will get `var1`

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `var1' for main:Object

And here,

```
if var1 = 1
  var1.zero?
end
```

`var1 =  1` will create var1 with value 1, so its not throwing error. when its executing `var1.zero?`.

Comment: In a common case, Ruby is lazy. Moreover, what mean 'read'? I know 'eval', but how it eval and not-eval simultaneously? Did you know how to work interpreter and can you describe this behaviour from this point. I'll be really appreciated for this.